# ActiveSync support across Windows CE/Mobile machines

Tags: windows-mobile, embedded, activesync

Is ActiveSync supported on all Windows CE x86 machines or are there any exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which of the active sync versions are your referring to?

Each active sync version supports different windows mobile versions:

> [ActiveSync 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsmobile/en-us/help/synchronize/activesync-download.mspx) works only with the
>   following versions of the Windows
>   Mobile operating system:
>
> - Windows Mobile 6.1
> - Windows Mobile 6.0
> - Windows Mobile 5.0
> - Windows Mobile 5.0 with Messaging and Security Feature Pack
> - Windows Mobile 2003 Second Edition
> - Windows Mobile 2003
>
> The following mobile device operating systems are supported by [ActiveSync 4.2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7269173a-28bf-4cac-a682-58d3233efb4c&displaylang=en):
>
> - Microsoft® Windows Mobile® 5.0
> - Messaging and Security Feature Pack for Microsoft® Windows Mobile® 5.0
> - Microsoft® Windows Mobile® 2003 Second Edition
> - Microsoft® Windows Mobile® 2003
> - Microsoft® Pocket PC 2002, Microsoft® Windows® CE OS version 3.0
> - Microsoft® Smartphone 2002, Microsoft® Windows® CE OS version 3.0

Also for active sync to support a certain device the OEM manufacturer **must** must install the Windows CE/Mobile OS with active sync compiled in (it can be omitted).

Comment: does active sync 4.2 support windows CE 5.0 or windows CE 6R2?

Comment: Active sync 4.2 only supports the Windows CE 5.0 family (Windows Mobile 5.0...), for Win CE 5 & 6 support you need to use Active Sync 4.5

Answer (score 4):

Windows CE is a modular, componentized OS.  It is completely up to the OEM whether or not they include the ActiveSync components into the OS image.  They can also include ActiveSync core support without any entity (Contact, Calendar, etc) sync capability.

The supported transport(s) (serial, USB, ethernet, RNDIS, etc) are completely OEM configurable as well.